# ASP.Net Core Boilerplate Angular 10 IIS HTTP error 400 on POST and PUT

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate

I currently have a basic ASP.Net Boilerplate. Core 3.1 project, which I am hosting on IIS and would like to serve an Angular 10 application on the same URL but on a different segment. I have successfully achieved this with the Angular on HTTP and the API on Https but having issues with both on HTTP and with the POST or PUT.

E.g.

API - https://application/api

Angular web app - https://application/app

Currently, my IIS is configured at the main ASP build directory. Within the build directory, I have an Angular directory where the release Angular application is built to.

My current is issue that when I make any POST/PUT I get a 400. In the log I get

*The required anti forgery header value "X-XSRF-TOKEN" is not present.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery header value "X-XSRF-TOKEN" is not present.*

Now when I look at a successful request Eg Angular running on HTTP and API running Https this header mentioned above is not present. What I do see is another request (OPTIONS) and get a status code of 204.

The request is correct in terms of payload if I set the attribute

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
```

POST and PUT are successful.

UPDATE - I have noticed that an XSRF-TOKEN cookie is generated if I navigate to Swagger. If I remove the cookie the POST and PUT are fine and I do not have the issue.

I think it should be fairly easy to resolve by stopping the XSRF token in the swagger implementation, but does this leave a potential security problem? Maybe another option is to get the Angular app to remove the cookie?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Keith

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by creating a HTTP Interceptor in the Angular app and checking for the 'XSRF-TOKEN' cookie then adding the header to the request.

```html
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AddCsrfHeaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const requestToken = this.getCookieValue('XSRF-TOKEN');
      return next.handle(req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', requestToken)
      }));
  }

  private getCookieValue(cookieName: string) {
    const allCookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split('; ');
    for (let i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = allCookies[i];
        if (cookie.startsWith(cookieName + '=')){
            return cookie.substring(cookieName.length + 1);
        }
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Add the interceptor to the module via providers:

```
@NgModule({ ...
 providers: [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AddCsrfHeaderInterceptorService, multi: true }
]
....
```

Comment: On added new users, the token is not usable API logs state that "The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user"